# Font Awesome not working in my sub theme of the Open Framework theme

Tags: theming

I have created a sub theme of [Open Framework](https://openframework.stanford.edu/) and everything seems fine, except for the Font Awesome feature. I add the following HTML in a block, but no icon shows up.

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
```

Is there something I need to do in order to enable Font Awesome?

**Edit:**
I can see the following in the source of my page, and I have verified that the path to `font-awesome.css` is valid.

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?n2r8cn");
@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css?n2r8cn");
@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?n2r8cn");
@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework/css/open_framework.css?n2r8cn");
@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework/css/ie.css?n2r8cn");
@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework_triangle/css/frontpage.css?n2r8cn");
@import url("http://www.example.com/sites/all/themes/open_framework_triangle/css/views.css?n2r8cn");</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is perfect - I think you probably just need to include the font-awesome.css library file itself.

There are a few ways to do this. I usually just include this in my pages `<head>` section:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But some people prefer to actually download the font-awesome.css from fontawesome.com, place it in their theme folder and point to that.

Comment: Thanks. The CSS file is included as expected. I see no errors in the console.

Comment: Could you possibly have an older version of font-awesome.css? Somewhere in the 3.x.x releases they changed from an .icon syntax to the .fa syntax they use today.

Comment: Spot on, I was mistakenly using v4 names. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal 8 way of attaching an external library is by manipulating the THEMENAME.libraries.yml that lives on the root of your custom theme or subtheme. You can add a call for that library like this:

```
fontawesome:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    component:
      //use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css: {}
```

Where "//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" is the path for the library on Font Awesome's CDN.

Also, you have to update your base theme configuration file (THEMENAME.info.yml) in order to add a pointer for that specific library you have just added:

```
libraries:
  - THEMENAME/font-awesome
```

That is it... Clean the cache and enjoy!